# Python datastructure for keys being mapped to auto-increment integer value

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I want to store a list of strings into a dictonary data structure, where the key will be the string I provided, and the value will be an auto-increment count.

```
text = ['hello', 'world', 'again']
ai_ds = {} # define the data structure here, used dict just for reference
ai_ds.add(text[0]) # should return 0
ai_ds.add(text[1]) # should return 1

auto_increment_ds.get(text[0]) # should return 0
```

I could do this by keeping a manual counter and then using that when inserting values in a dictionary, but I wanted to know if there is any default data structure like this in python.

Comment: What if an earlier entry is deleted? Are things renumbered then, or does the gap in the numbering remain? Is such gap number re-used later?

Comment: Is the complete list known at  creation time of  the data structure, or do you need later additions?

Comment: i wont do any deletion here.... i am mainly trying to map string to integers here. i could find the whole complete list, but that would require a lot of additional work, so I would prefer to keep on adding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dict with setdefault will work fine:

```
d = {}
d.setdefault("a", len(d))
d.setdefault("b", len(d))
d.setdefault("a", len(d))
print(d) # a=0, b=1
```

Comment: such a nice and easy solution, thanks :)

Comment: One-liner to avoid `.setdefault` repetition: `d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))` (`collections.defaultdict`). Then `d['something']` adds 'something' with new number.

Answer (score 0):

In case you string values are unique entries:

```py
text = ['hello', 'world', 'again']
d = {}    
d[text[0]] = len(d)    
d[text[1]] = len(d)    
d[text[2]] = len(d)
print(d)

{'hello': 0, 'world': 1, 'again': 2}
```